# Accessing an Endpoint in a Kubernetes Pod but get connection error

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm learning microservice with docker and k8s.
This project is a simple node.js express app and I tried to add a reverse proxy in it.
I already pushed the image (both the express app as well as the reverse proxy) to my docker hub.

Now I encounter a problem when I tried to access an endpoint in my pods.
My pod is running, and when I tried the endpoint:

curl:curl http://my-app-2-svc:8080/api/health

I get connection refused, I'm wondering what' wrong with that?

It seems that there are some problem with the liveness probe..
When I describe the pods: it shows:

**Liveness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.55.232:8080/health": dial tcp 192.168.55.232:8080: connect: connection refused**

[image]

Here is my github link for this project: https://github.com/floatingstarlight/Microservice

Can anyone helps me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 8080
...
```

If you asked for liveness probe, you need to implement it or your pod will be seen as a failure and restart every now and then. You can update your [server.js](https://github.com/floatingstarlight/Microservice/blob/main/server.js) to the minimum as follow to get up and running:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/health', (req, res) => {
  res.send('ok')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})
```